# SSH2 commandline not working from Windows

Tags: ssh

I have F-secure SSH client installed on Windows and OpenSSH server running on MAC OSX.
I have successfully configured public-key /private key authentication.
I login to the F-secure client software and input the username and server and say connect, it connects to the MAC terminal without prompting password.
Now I open the command prompt on the same windows box and try an scp2 using the scp2.exe. This also copies files without prompting password.
Now using ssh2.exe username@server , prompts for password .
I checked the identification file and userkeys all seems to be perfect .
What could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

I found it out.
ssh2 -o "AllowedAuthentications publickey" username@host
works as expected

Comment: Congrats!  Mark your answer as solved